# Django test error arguments 0 given

Tags: django, testing, arguments

I'm having trouble running this function:

```
def test_custom_mail_server_connection(host, port, user, password, use_tls, recipient):
    '''
    Test connection of mailing server with given user params
    returns None if mail is sent successfully, a string containg the error otherwise
    '''
    result = None
    message_list = []

    tenant = get_tenant_by_schema_name(connection.schema_name)

    # create new mail_connection
    mail_connection = mail.get_connection()
    mail_connection.host = host
    mail_connection.port = port
    mail_connection.username = user
    mail_connection.password = password
    mail_connection.use_tls = use_tls

    from_email = '%s <%s>' % (tenant.name, mail_connection.username)
    subject = _(u'%(name)s: SMARTFENSE - Prueba de servidor de correo propio') % {'name': tenant.name}

    mail_content = SimpleTemplateResponse("emails/email_server_test.html", {
        'host': host,
        'port': port,
        'user': user,
        'use_tls': use_tls,
    }, content_type="text/html", charset="utf-8").render().content

    msg = mail.EmailMessage(
        subject,
        mail_content,
        from_email,
        [recipient]
    )

    msg.content_subtype = 'html'
    message_list.append(msg)

    try:
        mail_connection.open()
        mail_connection.send_messages(message_list)
    except Exception as e:
        result = "%s" % e
    finally:
        mail_connection.close()

    set_mail_connection_config(mail_connection, 'default')

    return result
```

That basically checks if a given mail host is right in order to use it.

I wrote this test:

```
def test_test_custom_mail_server_connection(self):
        result = test_custom_mail_server_connection('smtp.gmail.com', 587, 'xxxxx@gmail.com',
                                                    'xxxxxxx', True, [])
        self.assertEqual(result, None)
```

And I'm getting the next error:

```
ERROR: Test connection of mailing server with given user params
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/Datos/Diamo/Smartfense/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/Volumes/Datos/Diamo/Smartfense/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/util.py", line 620, in newfunc
    return func(*arg, **kw)
TypeError: test_custom_mail_server_connection() takes exactly 6 arguments (0 given)
```

I tried changing the amounts of arguments and then I got the same error PLUS another one, like this:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_test_custom_mail_server_connection (lmsplatform.tests.test_services.LmsPlatformServicesTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/Datos/Diamo/Smartfense/smartfense/lmsplatform/tests/test_services.py", line 120, in test_test_custom_mail_server_connection
    'xxxxxxxxxx', True,)
TypeError: test_custom_mail_server_connection() takes exactly 6 arguments (5 given)

======================================================================
ERROR: Test connection of mailing server with given user params
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/Datos/Diamo/Smartfense/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/Volumes/Datos/Diamo/Smartfense/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/util.py", line 620, in newfunc
    return func(*arg, **kw)
TypeError: test_custom_mail_server_connection() takes exactly 6 arguments (0 given)
```

I found a couple of guys having through the same problem, but no solutions AT ALL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method `test_custom_mail_server_connection` is being treated as a test. Rename it to something else, e.g. `do_custom_mail_server_connection`.

You can then rename `test_test_custom_mail_server_connection` to `test_custom_mail_server_connection` if you wish.

Comment: Tried changing method name and doing import with an alias, still doesn't work.

Comment: You need to show your current code and traceback. You shouldn't get either of errors in your question after making the changes I suggested.

Comment: I already showed everything, the code and the tracebacks. You're not reading what I say. The second error was made on purpose to show that i got two differents tracebacks errors of the same method in the same execution. I can see that it is running some sort of parallel methods.

Comment: I didn't realise that the `takes exactly 6 arguments (5 given)` was a deliberate error by you, but that doesn't change the key part of my answer. You need to rename the method to `test_custom_mail_server_connection` to `do_custom_mail_server_connection`. You said that still doesn't work - that means you need to show what you changed the code to and what error you get, because you certainly wouldn't get `test_custom_mail_server_connection() takes exactly 6 arguments (0 given)` any more.

Comment: Ok,I thought the issue was that the method STARTED with "test".  I changed the name from "test_custom_mail_server_connection" to "do_test_custom_mail_server_connection". It didn't work, now I see that the "test" word cannot be included at all in the method def.

Comment: I tried do_custom_mail_server_connection and it works just fine.Thanks man!

Comment: I'm surprised that `do_test_custom_mail_server_connection` didn't work - the [default for unittest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestLoader.testMethodPrefix) is methods beginning with `test`. In any case, glad that you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was that the method I was trying to test was called `test_custom_mail_server_connection`, I thought the problem was that it started with "test" and changed it to `do_test_custom_mail_server_connection` and still it didn't work.
The solution was to completely remove the word "test" of the method name: `do_custom_mail_server_connection`

***Solution:*** **If you want to test a method, you shouldn't include the word "test" in it.**